# upload image in registration form in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

I want to save my model in database and upload my picture to server I want to do it all when I hit the save button

My view model is:

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public String Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Display(Name = "title")]
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "full text")]
    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string PostImage { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TagCheckBox> TagList { get; set; }

}
```

and Create.cshtml :

```
@model First.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.PostViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))   {   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostTitle, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, "لینک ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "form-control", data_slug = "#PostTitle" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and controller :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Address,PostTitle,PostContent,PostImage,TagList")] PostViewModel postViewModel,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string fileName = "1.jpg";
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/blog"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(postViewModel);
            }
            var selectedTags = ReconsileTags(postViewModel.TagList);

            Post post = new Post
            {
                PostTitle = postViewModel.PostTitle,
                PostContent = postViewModel.PostContent,

                Address = postViewModel.Address,
                Tags = selectedTags
            };
            post.PostImage = fileName ;
            post.AuthorId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            db.Posts.Add(post);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

the file (HttpPostedFileBase) is null !? 
please help me to solve this. (I'm newbie in asp mvc )

Comment: Change name attribute of file, Instead of `...name="fileUpload"/>` use `...name="file"/>`

Comment: Just another reason to always use a view model and strongly typed HtmlHelper methods

Comment: Note also `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostImage)` is pointless - you do not generate a form control for `PostImage`

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla Thank you my friend it's worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `<input name="fileUpload"/>` to `<input name="file"/>` and it's work well
Thanks to @KartikeyaKhosla for help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter, remove it and do something like the following:

```
HttpFileCollectionBase fileCollection = Request.Files;
if(fileCollection.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var file in fileCollection)
    {
        // do something with HttpPostedFileBase object
    }
}
```